# Join MySQL table using Chumper datatables library in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, datatable

I'm trying to use the `Chumper datatables library` in `Laravel 4.2` `https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable` to display a table on a page.
I did join my `branch_users` table and `users` table together and everything working fine. see as below.

```
$branchs = DB::table('branch_users')
        ->join('users', 'branch_users.employee_id', '=', 'users.employee_id')
        ->select('branch_users.branch_code as branch_code',
          'branch_users.branch_name as branch_name', 
          'branch_users.employee_id as employee_id',
'users.firstname_th as firstname', 'users.lastname_th as lastname')->get();
```

When I `print_r($branchs)` I get something like this

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [branch_code] => 333 [branch_name] => Robinson 
[employee_id] => 1000169 [firstname] => John [lastname] => Doson )...
```

The problem is after I make a table I got an Ajax error.

Do you know how to fix them? Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
return Datatable::query($branchs)
    ->showColumns('branch_code', 'branch_name', 'employee_id', 'firstname', 'lastname')
    ->searchColumns('branch_code', 'branch_name', 'employee_id', 'firstname', 'lastname')
    ->orderColumns('branch_code', 'branch_name', 'employee_id', 'firstname', 'lastname')
    ->addColumn('Edit', function($model) {
        return '<a href=branchs/'.$model->id.'/edit class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>';
    })
    ->addColumn('Delete', function($model) {
        return 
        Form::open(array('method'=> 'DELETE', 'route' => array('branchs.destroy', $model->id))).    
        Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=> 'btn btn-danger')).                 
        Form::close();
    })
    ->make();
```

View:

```
{{ Datatable::table()
 ->addColumn('Branch Code','Branch Name', 'Employee ID','First Name','Last Name','Edit','Delete')
 ->setUrl(route('api.branchs'))
 ->render() }}
```

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: This is Ajax error.
" DataTables Warning: table od=LFoYCLEj - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7 "